Scoring in Multiple Linear Regression with Cross_Val_Score
I am getting scoring criteria from cross_val_score that doesn't look like default or entered (scoring='r2') r2 values. The value looks like RMS or Neg Mean Error.
I've looked at prediction values over different size test datasets from simple Train Test Split and although the returned r2 metric looks low in some cases (0.14 to 0.97) the predicted Ages are reasonable given the stratification of the original dataset (predicted Age of 15 versus real of 10 isn't terrible for usage needs of this model).
Here is original model building code:
#Using training and testing splits to check for model accuracy and overfitting
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dftotal_ni, dfy_ni, test_size=0.12, random_state=42)
score = lm_ni.score(X_test, y_test)
print(score)

0.5729935257330477
#this isn't terrible for needed purposes
Yhat_test = lm_ni.predict(X_test)
#Plot the relationaship between the Actual and Predicted Ages
plt.scatter(Yhat_test, y_test)
plt.xlabel("Actual Age (years)")
plt.ylabel("Predicted Age")
plt.show()

Predicted v Actual Ages:

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score as r2
from sklearn.metrics import root_mean_squared_error as rms
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from numpy import mean, std
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Create new model for KFolds
lm_ni_val = LinearRegression()
scoring = 'r2'

# Evaluate the model of KFolds
scores = cross_val_score(
    lm_ni_val, dftotal_ni, dfy_ni, scoring=scoring, cv=8, n_jobs=-1)

# Mean and standard deviation of accuracy
print('Accuracy: %.3f ,\nStandard Deviations :%.3f' %
      (mean(scores), std(scores)))

Accuracy: -5076.400 ,
Standard Deviations :12227.956
#these values make no sense as r2 given multiple iterations of Train Test Split I looked at using the y_test and predicted y for different index breakdowns

It might be due to Data Mismatch. So ensure that dftotal_ni (features) and dfy_ni (target) are aligned correctly. Cross-validation could be seeing unexpected values or data splits, leading to strange results.
Check Negative R² values. In some cases, r2 can return negative values when the model fits very poorly. Negative r2 indicates that the model performs worse than a horizontal line predicting the mean value of y. However, values as extreme as -5076 suggest something unusual.
If the features in dftotal_ni are not scaled properly, this could distort the model's performance across different folds, resulting in large variability or extreme scoring. It might help to apply scaling before running cross-validation, especially if some features have a wide range of values.
The linear regression model might be suffering from overfitting or underfitting depending on the dataset's characteristics or how the folds are stratified. If you’ve accidentally defined a custom scoring function or modified something (e.g., used rms instead of r2), that might explain the different score outputs. Double-check that scoring='r2' is set correctly. I think if you try to resolve these, it might work better.

Appreciate the ideas. Of them, the data mismatch shouldn't be an issue as simple: #Using training and testing splits to check for model accuracy and overfitting
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dftotal_ni, dfy_ni, test_size=0.12, random_state=23)
score = lm_ni.score(X_test, y_test)
print(score)
Seems to work fine (X_test and y_test are built off the same original dftotal_ni and dfy_ni as the cross_val_score that is seemingly not returning an r2

Also, I did at one point used scaled values for the model build and received the same r2 values as well as feature weights. The model itself doesn't seem to particularly under or overfit given the predicted values as per the figure I uploaded.

I guess another way to say all of that is the R2 for the picture is 0.57 and I've seen between 0.14 and 0.97 depending on what partitioning happened to the 35 rows in dftotal_ni. But, the reported cross_val_score (also using KFold) has no instances of R2 < 1.0 and all large negative numbers.
